# Cleaning Up Xcode to Free Up Disk Space

Tags: xcode

I'm an iOS app developer using Xcode on my Intel-based MacBook Pro. With Xcode Version `15.0` installed, I've noticed it's taking up a significant amount of space on my disk. To optimize storage without risking my development environment, I'm considering cleaning up some Xcode-related files. However, I'm unsure about the purpose of each option listed in the screenshot below and which files are safe to delete. Could you please help me understand what each option means and advise on which files I can safely remove?

[image: Xcode storage]

Comment: Individual archives can be deleted from the Organizer window. Select Window > Organizer from Xcode. You might want to keep the latest few versions of apps that are live (needed for crash analysis?).

Comment: Thanks much! How about project build data and indexes? What are they and could those be cleaned up as well?

Comment: You can certainly delete the build data and indexes, also the caches, but they will be re-created when Xcode is next re-started. This means, a few GB will again be consumed again as soon as Xcode is re-started.